# PHP Framework that allows me to deal with HTML?

Tags: php, html, frameworks

Is there any PHP framework/library that allows me to do something like:

```
$element = $html->getElementByName("name");
$element->changeAttribute("class", "myClass");
echo $html->display;
```

I know that something like this is possible with javascript, but I need it to be PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
  <?php
      $doc = new DOMDocument();
      $doc->load( 'books.xml' );

      $books = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "book" );
      foreach( $books as $book )
      {
          $authors = $book->getElementsByTagName( "author" );
          $author = $authors->item(0)->nodeValue;

          $publishers = $book->getElementsByTagName( "publisher" );
          $publisher = $publishers->item(0)->nodeValue;

          $titles = $book->getElementsByTagName( "title" );
          $title = $titles->item(0)->nodeValue;

          echo "$title - $author - $publisher\n";
      }
  ?>
```

Just use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) class (For HTML use `loadHTMLFile` or `loadHTML` instead of `load`)

Answer (score 4):

No need for a framework. Just use [PHP's DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Answer (score 2):

Check out the various methods in the [DOMDocument](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class. Of course, remember that you need to load your html into a DOMDocument object using [loadHTML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) before you can manipulate it.